# can't reset method:already connected error at rest get service

Tags: java, rest, restful-architecture

I know this question has been asked many times I am writing it because I could not see an exact answer for that question. When I use following get service I get "java.net.ProtocolException: Can't reset method: already connected".

You can see the snippted below. For privacy reasons , I cannot share the get request link.

Thank you guys

```
      try {
        URL url = new URL("https://......");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            return true;
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried a different URL? It looks like it should work... Can you maybe attach the full stack trace?

Comment: yea it works as you told me tthe problem was URL. Thank you Jan